# Insert a new line to textarea using javascript (IE bug ?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, textarea

I'm trying to implement following functionality. I would like to be able to catch keystroke of semicolon character and change it to automatically add new line after pressing this key. In code it looks like this :

```
var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
if (keyCode == 59){
            e.preventDefault();     
            var tmpStyle = j$("#styleEditor").val();                
            tmpStyle += ";\n";
            j$("#styleEditor").val(tmpStyle);                               
}
```

So, firstly i'm catching this key (with "keypress" event), then I'm stopping it normal behaviour and at the end I'm adding semicolon and new line character to the end of textarea content.

Now, everything works fine on FF, Chrome. However on IE 9 it behaves really strange - instead of adding new line it adds .. white space. Then, if backspace this white space and type ";" again it works as expected. You can reproduce it by firstly typing some other characters and then typing semicolon.

I've also noticed that removing e.preventDefault() removes this issue, although then it paste two semicolons into textarea. Can somebody help me with it ?

You can chceck my small demo on [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ampartumpur/pmzzd56w/)

Comment: try this one:
tmpStyle = ";\r\n";

Comment: i've already tried this, without effect

Comment: have you added <!DOCTYPE html> to the top of your html file , sometimes such little things matters

Comment: yes it is added - jsfiddle, where the demo is placed, automatically takes care about that things

Comment: ok, you can try "\n/g" for IE 9

Comment: \n/g ?? how should I type it to tmpStyle += "\n"; ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `e.preventDefault()` and use event `keyup` instead of `keypress`.

```
function checkForSemicolons(e) {

    var style = j$("#styleEditor").value;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (keyCode == 59) {
        //e.preventDefault();   
        var tmpStyle = j$("#styleEditor").val();
        tmpStyle += "\n";
        j$("#styleEditor").val(tmpStyle);


    }
}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pmzzd56w/3/

Comment: This solution doesn't work at all. It should add new line after semicolon and in your solution it even do not get into if clause. It's strange but in keyup code of semicolon has changed. I also tried to change this to correct one. Then it enters the if clause, however issue still exists

Comment: Maybe it's a clue why it is not working on my side. On which browser have you checked this ? I was checking it on Chrome and IE 9. After your comment I've also checked it on FF and indeed, it works under FF. But on Chrome and IE 9 it doesn't work

Comment: @Vijay Notice, that `keyCode`s are different when using `keypress` or `keydown/up`.